# How to save only the changed checkboxes to local memory

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got myself totally confused.  My code loads checkboxes from external source, then uses .setitem() and .getitem() to save/restore the checkbox status.  This all works.  The problem is that my real code has 150 checkboxes and each time the user ticks/unticks a checkbox ALL the checkboxes are being stored to local memory which slows things down (you can see this from the console).  I just want local-storage to hold the checkboxes with changed status, not to hold all 150 of them.  I think this just needs an 'if' statement for .setitem() but nothing I've tried seems to work.  Any ideas much appreciated.  https://jsfiddle.net/bk50ymv9/

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js

<input id="MainMenuResetButton" type="button" value="Clear" />

<div id="CountryCheckboxContainer"></div>
<div id="YearCheckboxContainer"></div>




$(function(){

function LoadExternalCheckboxesAndCode(){

var divs_affected_by_onChange = ('#CountryCheckboxContainer, #YearCheckboxContainer')
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
$checkboxes = $(":checkbox");

 $(divs_affected_by_onChange).on("change", function(){
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
      console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'checkboxValues' ) ) );
});


// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
};


// Clear checkboxes
MainMenuResetButton.onclick = function() {

localStorage.removeItem("checkboxValues");
console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'checkboxValues' ) ) );
$('#CountryCheckboxContainer label input').prop('checked', false);
$('#YearCheckboxContainer label input').prop('checked', false);
};


// Load Checkboxes from external file
$.get('https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0', function(data){
 var $data= $(data); $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLCountryStorage'));
$("#YearCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLYearStorage'));

LoadExternalCheckboxesAndCode();    //THIS CALLS .setitem() & .getitem() code
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is somewhat simplified approach. It gathers the ids of all the checked checkboxes into a single string selector like `#id1, #id2, ...` and stores that then retrieves it and uses that as a selector to set the checkboxes. :

#### [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk50ymv9/4/)

```
$(function() {

  var $containers = $('#CountryCheckboxContainer, #YearCheckboxContainer');
  $containers.on("change", "input", function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
    var selected = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    selected = '#' + selected.join(',#');
    localStorage.setItem('selected_checkboxes', selected);
    console.log('setting selected ids: ',selected);
  });
 
  // Clear checkboxes
  $('#MainMenuResetButton').click(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("selected_checkboxes");
    $containers.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
    console.log('removed selected ids: ');
  }); 
  
  // Load Checkboxes from external file
  $.get('https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0', function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLCountryStorage'));
    $("#YearCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLYearStorage'));  
    var selected = localStorage.getItem('selected_checkboxes'); 
    if (selected && selected != '') $(selected).prop('checked', true);
    console.log('retrieved and set selected ids: ', selected);
  });
});
```

## Original answer:

Change your selector to grab only the checked checkboxes like `$checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');` and move it so that it is inside the on change event handler so it is refreshed on each call like this:

#### [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk50ymv9/3/)

```js
$(function() {

  function LoadExternalCheckboxesAndCode() {
    var divs_affected_by_onChange = $('#CountryCheckboxContainer input, #YearCheckboxContainer input')l
    var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};


    $(divs_affected_by_onChange).on("change", function() {
      $checkboxes = $(':checkbox:checked');
      checkboxValues = {};
      $checkboxes.each(function() {
        checkboxValues[this.id] = true;
      });
      localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')));
    });
    // On page load
    $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
  };


  // Clear checkboxes
  MainMenuResetButton.onclick = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem("checkboxValues");
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')));
    $('#CountryCheckboxContainer label input').prop('checked', false);
    $('#YearCheckboxContainer label input').prop('checked', false);
  };


  // Load Checkboxes from external file
  $.get('https://c2ect538.caspio.com/dp.asp?AppKey=b8a94000b0cf30c15313458e91a0', function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $("#CountryCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLCountryStorage'));
    $("#YearCheckboxContainer").html($data.find('#ExternalHTMLYearStorage'));

    LoadExternalCheckboxesAndCode(); //THIS CALLS .setitem() & .getitem() code
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="MainMenuResetButton" type="button" value="Clear" />

<div id="CountryCheckboxContainer"></div>
<div id="YearCheckboxContainer"></div>
```

Comment: @DelightedDDD I'm sure you are on the right track here but I get errors when I run your snippet and when I try to put into the fiddle

Comment: @Silverburch no errors for me https://jsfiddle.net/bk50ymv9/1/  What errors are you seeing exactly? Can you provide an updated fiddle that shows the errors?

Comment: @DelightedDDD do the following in your fiddle.  (1) press 'Clear' - run  (2) tick 'Austria' & '2013' - run (3) tick 'Albania' - run (4) UNtick 'Albania' - run.   I get 'Albania' coming back on all major browsers.  Other combinations also do weird things.

Comment: @Silverburch ah I see, I forgot to call `checkboxValues = {};` before the loop, fixed above

Comment: @Silverburch I also changed your selectors to `$('#CountryCheckboxContainer input, #YearCheckboxContainer input')` as your should really be binding to the inputs, not their containers.

Comment: @Silverburch also see my updated simpler approach outlined above

Comment: @DelightedDDD that is really slick coding and I've learned well.  Your help much appreciated.